# How to stdin a file from the clipboard on Terminal?

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, clipboard

I'd like to replace my clipboard to its base64-encoded representation. One of my tasks includes to be able to pipe in a copied file into `base64`.

For copied texts I can simply do:

```sh
pbpaste | base64 | pbcopy
```

Unfortunately, `pbpaste` returns just the name (not the full path) of my last copied element in Finder.

How can I do the above for a copied file, not plain text?

Answer (score 0):

When the clipboard contains a file *name*:

```bsh
base64 "$(pbpaste)" | pbcopy
```

---

If you don't know what the clipboard contains, some text or a filename, you could do:

```bsh
contents=$(pbpaste)
if [[ -f "$contents" ]]; then
    # it's a file, grab the file contents
    contents=$(cat "$contents")
fi
echo "$contents" | base64 | pbcopy
```

`echo` adds a trailing newline, you might want

```sh
printf '%s' "$contents" | ...
```

Comment: I wish it was that easy. I know how I could get the contents of a file giving its path, but `pbpaste` only returns the file name **without** its full path. `cat "$(pbpaste)"` will fail if I'm not in the folder of my copied file.

Comment: There might be an applescript invocation that asks the finder window what directory it's in, but you'll probably want to ask in [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) to get help with that. Other than that, I don't see how you can solve this by relying on finder for any assistance..

Answer (score 0):

Using AppleScript this can be done like so:

```sh
base64 "$(osascript -e 'POSIX path of (the clipboard as «class furl»)')" | pbcopy
```